# Is my SQL Merge statement correct, can be improved, or things to consider?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, merge

My question is the result of a bit of paranoia. I've had to work on older versions of SQL server and handled a merge scenario by simply deleting and re-inserting, but the time has come to digest the merge statement.

I have a need table:

```
tbl_Need (NeedID PK int)
```

And a project table:

```
tbl_Project (ProjectID PK int)
```

And a junction table:

```
tbl_ProjectNeed (NeedID PK FK int, ProjectID PK FK int)
```

A delimited string such as **'1|2|3'** (@Needs) is sent to the update stored procedure. In the past, I'd delete, and then split and iterate over the string to re-insert. Pseudo example:

```
delete from tbl_ProjectNeed WHERE ProjectID = @ProjectID
IF @Needs IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    -- Here I insert with the help of a table based function
    INSERT INTO tbl_ProjectNeed ( ProjectID, NeedID )
    SELECT @ProjectID, split.Data FROM udf_MyFunction(@Needs)
END
```

It's time to move up in the world and understand **merge**. I have what you would say a bit of a brain blockage with it. I don't fully understand it yet but I'm sure it'll click soon:

```
MERGE INTO tbl_ProjectNeed WITH (HOLDLOCK) AS Target
USING
(
    SELECT 
         @ProjectID AS ProjectID
        ,cast(split.[data] as int) AS NeedID
    FROM udf_MyFunction(@Needs) split
    WHERE NULLIF(split.[Data], '') IS NOT NULL
) AS Source
ON (Target.ProjectID = Source.ProjectID 
AND Target.NeedID = Source.NeedID)

WHEN NOT MATCHED BY Source THEN
    DELETE
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY Target THEN
    INSERT (ProjectID, NeedID) VALUES (Source.ProjectID, Source.NeedID)
;
```

Because I don't fully understand it yet (still working on it) I want to know:

1. Is my merge statement technically correct?
2. Can my merge statement be improved?
3. Are there any potential pitfalls to it?

So from what I'm understanding, it more or less creates a JOIN scenario, and then you perform operations on what is and isn't matched. Okay, but good gosh the syntax still feels foreign. Also, google searches result in a ton of "Be careful, watch out for, and the list goes on and on."

**Update**

It appears to do what I want, but initial appearances don't always prove the test of time.

**Update 2**

My split function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].udf_GenerateTableFromDelimitedString] 
(   
    @String varchar(max)
   ,@Delimiter varchar(10)
)
RETURNS TABLE 

AS
RETURN 
(
    WITH Split(stpos,endpos)
    AS(
      SELECT 0 AS stpos, CHARINDEX(@Delimiter,@String) AS endpos
      UNION ALL
      SELECT cast(endpos+1 as int), 
             CHARINDEX(@Delimiter,@String,endpos+1)
      FROM Split
      WHERE endpos > 0
    )
    SELECT 'Id' = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)),
    'Data' = 
    SUBSTRING(@String,stpos,COALESCE(NULLIF(endpos,0),LEN(@String)+1)-stpos)
  FROM Split
)
```

Comment: First thing I would look at is getting rid of the split function. Most splitters have loops/cursors in them. Some better options can be found here. http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings But even better than improving a splitter is to eliminate the need for it. A table valued parameter would be a much better approach than a delimited string.

Comment: @SeanLange The delimited string is a side effect of the application, one of which I'm stuck with for the moment, but thank you for the link. Reading that now.

Comment: And even though this article is a few years old now it is still worth reading. https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/

Comment: Understand about being stuck. If you split function is using loops that is some low hanging fruit to help improve performance.

Comment: @SeanLange I added my function to the bottom of the question :)

Comment: That will work but isn't the fastest splitter out there. Certainly FAR better than the nasty looping ones we usually see.

Comment: Thank you @SeanLange. You've always been helpful.